# The mug handle is not in the place I expected

Tags: modeling

I am making a mug in blender based on a picture. I make the make in Front Ortho and it's just fine but when I look at it from different angles it looks completely wrong. Why is this happening?

[image]

[image]?

Comment: You probably extruded it from a perspective where it looked right, but was in other directions too. I suggest just using the arrows or use Extrude [E] + X or Y or Z

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when you extrude with <kbd>CTRL + LMB🖱</kbd>. It's better to model objects like that bevelling a curve and combining them with <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd> later. Bevelling a curve lets you shape the object any way you want changing the curve as long as it is in 2D mode. And the handle is not choppy then.

Comment: I agree.. but maybe it's worth pointing out that if you _do_ want to extrude using ctrl-click, if you do it in an orthographic view, the extrusions will always be in the view's XY, so no twisting.